# Lying to current employer about new job

Tags: new-job

I'm thinking of applying for a new job, and I have two hypothetical questions.

1. If I get a new job, and my current employer asks what new company I'll be working for, are there any consequences with lying about what new
   Company I'm going to? For example, I don't want my current employer to know where I'm going to I lie and say something like I'm taking time off
   Or doing a career transition. Does anyone see any consequences with doing this?
2. Let's say hypothetically my current performance at my current job is not going well, and I have a feeling I might be fired or let go. However, at the same time Im also interviewing with other companies and I ask that I'm being discreet about finding a new job. If I get the new Job, and I find out afterwards I get fired, could the new company find out somehow?

Comment: Lots of stuff could happen.  Why you you lie - just them where you are going is not their business.   If you get the new job why would the old company fire you?

Comment: Realistically it's best to just say, "I do not wish to disclose that" instead of lying when asked where you will be going.

Comment: Also if you're in the USA, most companies won't publically reveal you were fired or why. They may disclose that you were let go of when asked but they won't disclose why.

Comment: Hypothethical make bad questions, particularly if they're of the variety that requires a crystal ball to answer. Questions here should have practical answers like "How can I avoid telling my old employer about the company I'm moving to?". And these questions have been asked before: [Q 1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21232), [Q 2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10280). VTC too broad.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to lie, you simply do not tell them. You answer, "I'd rather not say."

In general, it is not considered getting fired if you put in notice before they fire you. If they ask you to not come back after the day you get notice, they are simply changing the notice period. If they were thinking of firing you and had not done it yet, that is nobody's business.

It is however best not to be in a position where you think you are going to get fired. Before you start your new job, you may need to do some soul searching about how you can do better in the new place.

Answer (score 2):

Lying is never a good idea and serves no purpose.  If your old job is curious just tell them that you are moving to another company that does not compete in the same business space.  Unless of course your reason for leaving is to go and work for a direct competitor.  In that case I would check my non-compete to verify that I wasn't doing anything I could get sued over.

Are you concerned with getting fired after putting in notice?  If that is the case ask the new job if you can start early.  From that moment on when asked in a interview why you left the job with company 'old', your answer should be to take a job with company 'new'